# Uploading a recorded video file using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, html5-video, blob, jquery-file-upload

I am creating an application [hosted at Server1] where I am recording a video and uploading it to a server [Server2]. I am using Ajax to upload the file. Once the recording finishes, I get the URL of the file [videoSrc] as 'blob:https://server1/a0080679-caaf-41b0-b6a0-ce41d1283476'. 
I am using the following code to upload the video using Ajax:

```
function uploadFile()
{
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('video', videoSrc);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        url: "https://server2/upload.php",
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 600000,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);


        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log("ERROR : ", e);
        }
    });

}
```

On the server-side (PHP), I am getting just the URL in the post parameter. I am not getting the file in the $_FILES directive.
Code:

```
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [video] => blob:https://server1/a0080679-caaf-41b0-b6a0-ce41d1283476
)
Array
(
)
```

How can I upload the recorded video? Please help.

Comment: where is your upload.php put code please

Comment: print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES);
move_uploaded_files($_FILES['video']['tmp_name'], 'video.mp4');

Comment: You should send value from file filed. lets supose your video field is is upload_video then     var data = new FormData(); var upload_video = $('#upload_video ').val();
    data.append('video', upload_video );

Comment: If you don't have input type file, then you will not get it as $_FILES. You only have url of video from client-end, then call curl or file_get_contents to download and save video on server.

Comment: I just have the URL of the video which was recorded on the client-side in javascript. I can't set the file input value. Only way left is Ajax. The file is on Server1 [blob:https://server1/a0080679-caaf-41b0-b6a0-ce41d1283476] and has to be sent to server2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the fix through trial and error. I was sending the URL of the blob (output of recording) created using createObjectURL(). I sent the blob directly using Ajax and PHP $_FILES received it.

Earlier Code:

```
var blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {
    type: 'video/mp4'
  });
//Creating blob url which is only valid for the browser
//where the application is running
var videoSrc = URL.createObjectURL(blob); 
var data = new FormData();
data.append('video', videoSrc);  //Incorrect: sending the Blob URL
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        url: "https://server2/upload.php",
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 600000,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);


        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log("ERROR : ", e);
        }
    });
```

Corrected Code:

```
var blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {
    type: 'video/mp4'
  }); 
var data = new FormData();
data.append('video', blob);  //Correct: sending the Blob itself
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        url: "https://server2/upload.php",
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 600000,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);


        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log("ERROR : ", e);
        }
    });
```

Comment: <?php
move_uploaded_files($_FILES['video']['tmp_name'], 'video.mp4');